# change variable in integrals , jacobian?

Tags: calculus, integration

how can this exterior product gives us the jacobian , when we have in $R^2$ this substitution of variables 
$$X=x+tz$$
$$T=x+t$$ the exersice says that jacobian is 
$$|dX\wedge dT|=|z-1||dx\wedge dt|$$, so why $|dX\wedge dT|$ is the jacobian , and why this equality is true ?

Answer (score 1):

Using the properties of the exterior product and the differential, you have

$$ dX \wedge dT  = (dx + z dt) \wedge (dx + dt) = dx \wedge dx + dx \wedge dt + z dt \wedge dx + zdt \wedge dt = dx \wedge dt + z(dt \wedge dx) = dx \wedge dt + - z(dx \wedge dt) = (1 - z)(dx \wedge dt). $$

In general, if you perform a change of variables from $(x,t)$ to $(X,T)$, then 
if you write $f(x,t) = (X(x,t), T(x,t))$ for the change of variables, you can check using the chain rule and the relevant definitions that

$$ dX \wedge dT = \det(df) \, dx \wedge dt $$

and thus the Jacobian $|\det(df)|$ is the (absolute value of the) factor that $dx \wedge dt$ is multiplied by to be equal to $dX \wedge dT$.

Comment: thank you very much , good job , but just i didn t get the last one , how can i check this .. :)

Comment: If $X = X(x,t)$ then $dX = \frac{\partial X}{\partial x} dx + \frac{\partial X}{\partial t} dt$. Write an analogous expression for $dT$ and compute $dX \wedge dT$ like I did in the answer.

Comment: well done , i got it thanks again

Comment: but i have i have an other question for you if you have time  :)??

Comment: You can post the question on the site and I'll try to answer if I have the time and know the answer.